# Different numbering for toc and chapter titles using titlesec package

Tags: xetex, pdftex, titlesec, thesis, books

I want the chapter titles in the ToC to be listed using arabic numbers, but want no numbering in the chapter title pages. Like here:

[image: toc.png]

and in the title page, it should be like:

[image: titlepage.png]

but without the number. Right now I add `\chap{1. Introduction}` to keep the number in the ToC. In the preamble, I have:

```
\usepackage[pagestyles, clearempty]{titlesec}
\newcommand\chap[1]{%
    {\centering}
   \chapter*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
  \markboth{#1}{#1}
  {\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{2.5ex}\filright}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Same for all chapters?

Comment: Yes same for all @Bernard

Comment: In this case, use  `\titleformat` without adding the chapter number (in the second argument) and format the table of contents with `titletoc` (the command is `titlecontents{chapter}{…}`). See details in §6 of the titlesec documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `titlesec` features.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles,clearempty]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\huge\bfseries\filright}
 {}% no number
 {0pt}
 {}
 [\vspace{2.5ex}{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Another}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The option `oneside` is used just to reduce the number of pages in the image.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, I was confused with the format options in titlesec. This looks neat!